# How to rerun the python script after a tkinter button press?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a script that does some webscraping for a product and then uses a playwright sequence to place the data to a website backend. I am using tkinter as the GUI to get the input from the user and after the script is done ask the user if they want to run the app again for another product. When I try to rerun the code by calling the **init** method on button press, I get an error that the Playwright should be running in Async mode, making me wonder if I have somehow made the entire thing into an infinite loop, since I have all my methods inside one class.
I have tried using os.exec command to restart the app, but that didn't work. I am pretty certain that just calling the __init__method is not the way to go, but can't figure out how to just rerun the script, starting from the **init** method.
Here is my relevant code so far:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox as mb
from requests_html import HTMLSession
import os
import tempfile
from docx import Document
from htmldocx import HtmlToDocx
import pyperclip as pc
from playwright.sync_api import Playwright, sync_playwright
import shutil


s=HTMLSession()


class Interface:
          
    
    def rerun(self):
        self.__init__(root)

    def quit(self):
        self.master.destroy()

    def confirm(self):
        ttk.Label(self.mainframe, text='The product has been updated.\nWould you like to update another one?').grid(column=1, row=5, sticky=E)
        ttk.Button(self.mainframe, text="Yes", command=self.rerun).grid(column=2, row=6, sticky=E)
        ttk.Button(self.mainframe, text="Quit", command=self.quit).grid(column=3, row=6, sticky=W)

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.productID = None
        self.thomannURL = None

        master.title("New Product  - CMS")

        self.mainframe = ttk.Frame(master, padding="3 3 12 12")
        self.mainframe.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, W, E, S))
        master.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        master.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        
        
        self.entry1 = StringVar()
        self.entry1_entry = ttk.Entry(self.mainframe, textvariable=self.entry1, width=20)
        self.entry1_entry.grid(column=2, row=1, sticky=(W, E))
        
        self.entry2 = StringVar()
        self.entry2_entry = ttk.Entry(self.mainframe, textvariable=self.entry2, width=20)
        self.entry2_entry.grid(column=2, row=2, sticky=(W, E))
        
        
        ttk.Label(self.mainframe, text="Enter Product ID:").grid(column=1, row=1, sticky=E)
        ttk.Label(self.mainframe, text="Enter product URL:").grid(column=1, row=2, sticky=E)
# the on_button method has been edited out to shorten the code snippet
        ttk.Button(self.mainframe, text="Run", command=self.on_button).grid(column=3, row=3, sticky=W)

        

        for child in self.mainframe.winfo_children(): 
            child.grid_configure(padx=5, pady=10)

        self.entry1_entry.focus()
        
        master.bind("<Return>", self.on_button)
        

root = Tk()
i = Interface(root)
 
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: It looks like some of the code in `__init__()` could go in a separate method. Why do you want to rerun `__init__()` within the class?

Comment: To be frank, this is my first tkinter application an I am not sure how to tackle it. The __init__ initializes my tkinter GUI which sould stay open until the user decides not to update another product. If you can point me in the right direction, that would be appreciated.